# If a GPU supports OpenGL ES 3.2, does it also support OpenGl 3.0?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

At the moment I am looking for a tablet to use the bike simulator app "BKOOL".
The Samsung Galaxy Tab S6 Lite is my current favorite and it meets almost all app requirements (https://www.bkool.com/en/apps?updateLocale=1), but I'm not sure about the GPU " ARM Mali-G72 MP3 ".
The ARM Mali-G72 MP3 supports OpenGL ES 3.2 (https://www.notebookcheck.net/ARM-Mali-G72-MP3-GPU.301008.0.html), but OpenGL 3.0 is required.

If a GPU supports OpenGL ES 3.2, does it also support OpenGL 3.0?

[image]

Comment: When you say "OpenGL 3.0", do you mean desktop OpenGL? Because most mobile GPUs don't support desktop GL of *any* version.

Comment: This is what it says in the requirements for "Android" on the BKOOL website: https://www.bkool.com/en/apps?updateLocale=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a typo. Most mobile GPUs don't support desktop GL of any version, so they probably meant OpenGL ES 3.0 (which is a valid version)

And yes, ES 3.0 is backwards compatible with ES 3.2.

Comment: I asked the Support-Team and they agreed.